# Die Bedeutung von "betreffen" im Zusammenhang mit "Vorwürfe"

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet der folgende Satz - "Diese Vorwürfe betreffen mich nicht" (Duden)?

> 1. Diese Vorwürfe beziehen sich nicht auf mich.
> 2. Diese Vorwürfe sind nicht von der Bedeutung.
> 3. Diese Vorwürfe haben keine Auswirkungen auf mich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schauen wir uns zwei Beispiele an:

> Einer der Mitarbeiter in meiner Firma muss etwa gestohlen haben, aber dieser Vorwurf betrifft mich nicht, da ich zu der Zeit im Urlaub war.

Hier ist die Bedeutung, dass sich die Vorwürfe nicht auf mich beziehen.

> Mein Kollege soll gefeuert werden, weil er gestohlen hat. Zum Glück betrifft mich der Vorwurf nicht.

Hier ist die Bedeutung, dass die potentielle Entlassung meines Kollegen keine Auswirkungen auf mich hat. Z.B., weil ich auch ohne ihn weiterarbeiten kann.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort!

Comment: In Beispiel 2 sagst Du, der Vorwurf betrifft Dich nicht, erklärst dann aber, dass die Entlassung des Kollegen Dich nicht betrifft. Das ist nicht schlüssig.

Comment: Das ist eine Verkürzung. Der Vorwurf führt zu einer Entlassung, die mich nicht betrifft. Daher betrifft mich auch der Vorwurf nicht.